# what is the meaning of ":d" in {currentDate:d}

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C# coding. Please tell me what does it mean by ":d" in {currentDate:d}
I find it in a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0 page

The code is as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
var name = Console.ReadLine();
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Hello, {name}, on {currentDate:d} at{currentDate:t}!");
Console.Write($"{Environment.NewLine}Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to C# World :).

`d`:- represent date in datetime
`t` :- represent time in datetime

DateTime.Now always give date and time of that moment

So Suppose `currentdate` is `6/3/2022 12:04:11 AM` then  you will get `Hello .... on 6/3/2022 at12:04 AM!`

`{currentDate:d}` :- `**6/3/2022**`

`{currentDate:t}` :- `**12:04 AM**`

I hope, you got the answer.